# clr DLL built as .NET 3.5 "requires later version" when referenced from a .NET 3.5 project.

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, clr

I built the dll using Visual Studio 2008 for .NET 3.5 targeted framework.

Loading it into a .NET project built in 3.5 gives the error

```
"OpenGLControl.dll", or one of its dependencies, requires a later version of the .NET Framework.... etc.
```

The dll shows a 'runtime version' of v2.0.50727.

Anyone experienced something similar? Any solutions?

According to [this site:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049.aspx)  that should be acceptable for a .NET 3.5 build.

Thanks!

Comment: The only time this happened to me that is similar to your situation is when i had a dll build for .Net CF and loaded it in a vs2010 project. I dont suppose you targeted the compact framework by mistake?

Comment: Nope, double checked.  None of the dependencies I built are either. :(

Answer (score 0):

In the end the issue was an unversioned dependency, although not listed as a higher framework version it seems VS2008 'assumed' it to be higher.  So not only must the dependencies by the same version or less, they must all have an explicit framework version.